# get images in json files

Tags: symfony, symfony4, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to create a PWA interface in my symfony app, right now I'm creating the manifest.json and trying to call images from the manifest to define the icons but instead of searching inside my public folder for the images, it's taking the path as a URL

Same problem happens in my sw.js file, since I can't link the pages and files that I want to cache
my manifest.json:

```
 {
    "name": "Hello World",
    "short_name": "Hello",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-128.png",
          "sizes": "128x128",
          "type": "image/png"
        }, {
          "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-144.png",
          "sizes": "144x144",
          "type": "image/png"
        }, {
          "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-152.png",
          "sizes": "152x152",
          "type": "image/png"
        }, {
          "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-192.png",
          "sizes": "192x192",
          "type": "image/png"
        }, {
          "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-256.png",
          "sizes": "256x256",
          "type": "image/png"
        }, {
          "src": "Agentassets/images/hello-icon-512.png",
          "sizes": "512x512",
          "type": "image/png"
        }],
    "lang": "en-US",
    "start_url": "Agent/Agent.html.twig",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "white",
    "theme_color": "white"
  }
```

and here's my sw.js

```
var cacheName = 'hello-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
  "Agent/Agent.html.twig",
  'AgentInterface/css/style.css',
  'AgentInterface/js/main.js'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: would you mind showing the code, because otherwise it's pretty difficult to see errors in your code or suggest relevant improvements beyond "well ... do it properly!"

Comment: I already showed my code, turns out the problem is not just the json, but it also happens in js files. I'm trying to make a PWA page, which needs service workers and a manifest.json, thing is I can't link to images from my json or to which pages I wanna cache from my sw.js file.